# load dynamic image from path in crystal report

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I want to show an image in my report , I save path of image in my sqlserver database and now I want to load image from path .I search all of internet for that and try all of guidance , I first insert image into my report and after that I go to `>Format Editor > picture > Graphic Location >` and insert path of image into the textarea like this `{Command.path}` but when I run , it doesn't show any picture . Now how should I do ? 
  I use visual studio 2013 and latest version of crystal report .

Answer (score 5):

Use a conditional formula to dynamically change the location of a report’s image.

1. Add an image to the report: `-> Insert` `-> Picture`
   This image will act as a placeholder.
   Ensure that the placeholder is the same size as the one that will be dynamically loaded, otherwise, the image will be scaled.
2. Change the image’s Graphic Location:
   `-> right click image`
   `-> select Format Graphic…`
   `-> select Picture tab`
   `-> click the conditional-formula button (looks like x+2)`
   `-> set the formula’s text to the name of the formula or parameter field that will contain the image’s URL`
   `-> save the formula and click the OK button`
   `-> save the report`

It worked for me.

> Source: cogniza.com

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f869fe3f-ee0f-4ecd-ae7c-9303e0b1f66f/dynamic-image-location-by-using-a-parameter?forum=vscrystalreports), you're doing it right.  Perhaps try to set a formula field equal to `{Command.path}` and use that instead to see if crystal just isn't parsing it properly?  That way you can display the formula field and see how it displays.  Perhaps you're storing it in the DB with quotation marks or spaces?  Alternatively, using a parameter should definitely work, so you could make a sub-report with `{Command.path}` as a parameter that it uses to load up the image.

Comment: tank you for reply , I remove every space in path and after that some picture shown and some picture didn't show

Comment: That indicates that either the path is invalid for the images that don't load (trailing spaces, or part of the path had a space in it that you need to escape, for example a folder named `Evil Whitespace`), or there's some kind of timeout going on on one end of the image exchange.  I expect that it's simply some badly named files/folders that have spaces that you are now stripping.  Take a look at the path stored in the db, the path you pass in crystal, and the path you need to access the file in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do it by:

1. Add a datasource for your report. Be sure to include the path image.
2. Add a default image.
3. From Format Editor > picture > Graphic Location , add the path image field.