# Insert image from database to report of crystal report c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Hello I have problem on my program c#, I should insert image from database to report of crystal report c#, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Image column in table of your DB ??

Just Google it 
look here :

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-image-from-database-in-Crystal-Report-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

there are many other ways, for example extract your image from DB and save it in a temp path then just use the path and load it in your RPT

explain more if it doesn't your need

Comment: I had already tried with this tutorial but I was not working , The FITTED image in the database is not online ( http : ..... ) but it is saved on your computer ( C : // ... )

Comment: So you mean there is a path in DB ?? or what do u have in your DB ??

Comment: in db there is path

Comment: actually it was my problem year ago, take look at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21095/Image-in-Crystal-Reports in this article load the image from path and save it on a datatable then pass it to the CR

Comment: and if your application run in the local machine(The computer that have the images) use this steps : 
    1- Add a datasource for your report. Be sure to include the path image.
   2- Add a default image.
   3- From Format Editor > picture > Graphic Location , add the path image field. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751890/load-dynamic-image-from-path-in-crystal-report